# C# ReSharper: suppress specific warnings on all targets of specific Attribute

Tags: c#, resharper, warnings, code-analysis

Example:

```
private string foo;
```

This rightfully emits warning `CS0649: Field 'foo' is never assigned`. If I add my custom attribute, though, I want the warning to be suppressed:

```
[Localize("foo")]
private string foo;
```

I know this is possible using [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). A library I'm using, [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), has an attribute that suppresses the same warning on every field it is used on, if ReSharper is running:

```
[JsonProperty("foo")]
private string foo;
```

I tried using `#pragma` directives on the Attribute class, played around with [In Source Suppression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx), but to no avail yet. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**: added an animation to show the desired behaviour when using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty on an unassigned field.

**Edit**: added clarification since the feature seems to be ReSharper-specific

[image: animation showing how JsonProperty attribute suppresses the warning]

Comment: Are you sure using JsonProperty attribute supresses this warning? Because I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your response. I've added an animation to show the behaviour with JsonProperty (using Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: But if you build that project - won't it emit CS0169 warning message still (in "Warnings" build tab)? Also, do you have Resharper installed?

Comment: @Evk You are right - the error list will still emit CS0169 in the Warnings tab. I don't usually check there because we're working with Unity3D, which mirrors part of the warnings to its own editor console.

I do use ReSharper, so this may well be a ReSharper-specific behaviour then. I'll check and reformulate my question if I find out any relation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the `[MeansImplicitUse]` attribute from [JetBrains.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations) package,
to your created attribute class. [step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HId4z.gif)

Answer (score 0):

`[UsedImplicitly]` attribute from [JetBrains.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations) should help you.
Also look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347692/best-practice-to-mark-a-method-that-is-called-via-reflection)

Comment: thank you very much! While `[UsedImplicitly]` indeed suppresses the warning, I only found out how to apply it to a single field. Optimally, I'd want to achieve that my `[Localize]` attribute makes it unnecessary to also specify `[UsedImplicitly]`, serving as a marker for ReSharper by itself. I didn't find any leads on how to achieve that in your linked articles - or did I miss something?