# Is it possible to create a custom attribute that suppresses specific warnings?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, custom-attributes

In the [Lara](https://github.com/integrativesoft/lara) framework, I have the custom attribute `LaraWebComponentAttribute` that flags classes for being created using reflection. Typically, the classes created this way will not be instantiated directly on the code and only through reflection.

Given that classes with this attribute will be instantiated more often than not through reflection and not directly, they get flagged with the compiler warning [CA1812: Avoid uninstantiated internal classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1812?view=vs-2019).

Is it possible to somehow modify my custom attribute so that it will automatically dismiss a specific compiler warning?

Comment: You know there's already a `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute` that does it?

Comment: @Clay that suppresses the warning when placed in the class that's yielding it. Is there any way to make my own custom attribute include the functionality of that attribute, so that my custom attribute suppresses them too?

Comment: That isn't a compiler warning but an analyzer warning. Analyzer rules are customizable (as in, you can write your own Roslyn analyzers) so in theory you could write your own CA1812 variant that specifically respects your attribute. This is likely more trouble than it's worth, though, compared to just disabling CA1812 altogether, or for an entire scope. The added value is limited, especially if your code relies heavily on classes getting instantiated through reflection. Worst case, a class that truly isn't used anywhere anymore gets left in the code base -- not exactly a firing mistake.

Comment: You could also look into code generation, to generate partial class with `[SuppressMessage]` for classes tagged with `[LaraWebComponentAttribute]`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 do you have any link to check out what code generation is?

Comment: @cat_in_hat https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn

Comment: Related question for ReSharper-specific warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641414/c-sharp-resharper-suppress-specific-warnings-on-all-targets-of-specific-attribu